# Ant - 1.8.3 and Junit @Ignore

Tags: ant, junit, junit4

Ant 1.8.3 is not ignoring the junit test class with @Ignore annotation. Where as Ant 1.8.1 ignores the test class perfectly.

This is how my test class looks like:

```
....
import org.junit.Ignore
import org.junit.Test      
....

@Ignore("Want to ignore this class tests")
public class TestClass extends ABCDTestCase {

@Test
public void testAbcd(){
....
}


}
```

After struggling for a day, found that ant-junit.jar in ant-1.8.3 is the culprit. When this ant-junit.jar of ant-1.8.3 is replaced with ant-junit.jar of 1.8.1 it works perfectly well.

Am i missing something here ? or is the only tweak which solves this problem ?

Comment: It sounds like a bug.  Did you report it?

Comment: No. We'll do it. Thank you :)